# iOS - Crash issue on reload table

Tags: ios, uitableview, crash, 64-bit, xcode7

after recently updating an app to 64 bit, and 7.1 im getting a crash on a reload of a table. Ive tried various begin/end update attempts, but nothing seems to resolve.

Behaviour is around 2 seconds of hang then crash - here code called, then is the crash.

```
 [myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

crash:

```
2015-11-02 20:10:24.827 ABC[43144:971620] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cbe9f45 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c663deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010caeceae -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 318
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010caff21b +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 59
    4   ABC                               0x0000000106d7d426 -[ABCViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] + 1926
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001087105cf __66-[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:]_block_invoke + 240
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010870fc5f -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 4876
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000108712898 -[UITableViewRowData ensureAllSectionsAreValid] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001084e3132 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 598
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001084fd1bf -[UITableView _updateSections:updateAction:withRowAnimation:headerFooterOnly:] + 403
    10  ABC                               0x0000000106d7b780 -[ABCTimesViewController updateData] + 8288
    11  ABC                               0x0000000106d79705 -[ABCTimesViewController connectionDidFinishLoading:] + 309
    12  CFNetwork                           0x000000010be689ae __65-[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:]_block_invoke + 69
    13  CFNetwork                           0x000000010be68952 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withConnectionAndDelegate:onlyActive:] + 199
    14  CFNetwork                           0x000000010be68aa7 -[NSURLConnectionInternal _withActiveConnectionAndDelegate:] + 48
    15  CFNetwork                           0x000000010bcd6452 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 104
    16  CFNetwork                           0x000000010bdc45eb ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 100
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d51449b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010d4f654b _dispatch_block_invoke + 716
    19  CFNetwork                           0x000000010bcc26f0 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext13_invoke_blockEPKvPv + 24
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cae94c4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
    21  CFNetwork                           0x000000010bcc25e9 _ZN19RunloopBlockContext7performEv + 137
    22  CFNetwork                           0x000000010bcc24a2 _ZN17MultiplexerSource7performEv + 282
    23  CFNetwork                           0x000000010bcc22c4 _ZN17MultiplexerSource8_performEPv + 72
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb16011 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb0bf3c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb0b3f3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010cb0ae08 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010dc2dad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    29  UIKit                               0x00000001083be30d UIApplicationMain + 171
    30  ABC                               0x0000000106d56cd1 main + 97
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d54892d start + 1
    32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Add the code where you are trying to edit a dictionary.

Comment: You can get the reason of crashing by adding "NSException" break point..

Comment: thanks, ill try that out